# Counting capital letters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to count the number of capital letters to detect the percentage of capital letters in a string. I tried to do it with a regular expression
`string.match(/[A-Z]*/)`, but that will only match the first combination of capital letters.

Comment: `string.scan(/[A-Z]/)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string.scan()` applies to the entire string, and should work for your use-case. The following should work:

```
your_string = "Hello World"
capital_count = your_string.scan(/[A-Z]/).length
```

Comment: I think you want `yourString.scan(/[A-Z]/).length`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways that do not involve converting the string to an array of characters.

```
CAPS = ('A'..'Z')
ALL_CAPS = CAPS.to_a.join
  #=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
CHAR_TO_BIN = 128.times.with_object({}) do |i,h|
  c = i.chr
  h[c] = (CAPS.cover?(c) ? 1 : 0)
end
  #=> {"\x00"=>0, "\x01"=>0, "\x02"=>0,...," "=>0, "!"=>0,...,
       "0"=>0, "1"=>0,..."9"=>0, ":"=>0, ";"=>0, "<"=>0, "="=>0,
       ">"=>0, "?"=>0, "@"=>0, "A"=>1, "B"=>1,..."Z"=>1, "["=>0,...,
       "a"=>0, "b"=>0,...,"z"=>0, "{"=>0,...,"\x7F"=>0} 

str = "The quick brown dog, 'Lightning', jumped over 'Bubba', the lazy fox"
```

**1: <s>Not very efficient, but</s> Fastest by far and reads well**

```
str.count(ALL_CAPS)
  #=> 3
```

**2: Efficient**

```
str.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t + (CAPS.cover?(c) ? 1 : 0) }
  #=> 3
```

**3: If you need to do it many times (may be faster than #2)**

```
str.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t + CHAR_TO_BIN[c] }
  #=> 3
```

**4: Delete all non-caps and count**

```
str.gsub(/[^A-Z]/,'').size
  #=> 3
```

or delete all caps and count:

```
str.size - str.gsub(/[A-Z]/,'').size
  #=> 3
```

Comment: A downvote? Oh, well. Could it be Bubba, for getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be interesting to compare the efficiency of the various methods suggested.

```
require 'fruity'

CAPS = ('A'..'Z')
ALL_CAPS = CAPS.to_a.join
  #=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
CHAR_TO_BIN = 128.times.with_object({}) do |i,h|
  c = i.chr
  h[c] = (CAPS.cover?(c) ? 1 : 0)
end

lower = ('a'..'z').to_a
upper = ('A'..'Z').to_a

L = 50_000
U = 10_000
```

The test string contains `L` randomly-drawn lower case letters and `U` randomly-drawn upper-case letters, shuffled.

```
str = L.times.map {lower.sample}.concat(U.times.map {upper.sample}).shuffle.join

compare do 
  scan   { str.scan(/[A-Z]/).length }
  count  { str.count(ALL_CAPS) }
  reduce { str.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t + (CAPS.cover?(c) ? 1 : 0) } }
  hsh    { str.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t + CHAR_TO_BIN[c] } }
  gsubA  { str.gsub(/[^A-Z]/,'').size }  
  gsubB  { str.size - str.gsub(/[A-Z]/,'').size }
end

Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 33 seconds.

count is faster than gsubB by 39x ± 10.0
gsubB is similar to scan
scan  is faster than gsubA by 3x ± 1.0
gsubA is similar to hsh
hsh   is similar to reduce
```

I was amazed by how fast [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count) is. I had assumed that Ruby would do an `include?` for every character in the string.  I was wrong. Looking at the source code there is a `C` function `tr_setup_table`, suggesting that Ruby is constructing a hash or something similar before doing the counting.

Comment: @theTinMan, I know you're interested in benchmarks; this one is quite surprising.